# Whats wrong with my python xor gate?

Tags: python-2.7, bitwise-operators

I am trying to solve this problem (https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1026). My code somewhat like below:

```
x = raw_input()
x = x.split(" ")
#print x
a = long(x[0])
b = long(x[1])
#print "a:",a,"b:",b
print a^b
```

When i submit my code I got WA (https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/runs/code/5405752). Where's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Probably because you are using `long` which adds an `L` when it prints out. An `int` would be sufficient and would avoid this issue (and would work in Python 3).

Comment: if I use int it also gives WA

Comment: What are you getting as output - I'm getting the expected output, `2` and `15`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the complete code that you submitted then(The code link is not available), please review the question. The question asks to answer the queries till EOF. There are multiple queries in a input file and your code will only process the first input.

try :

`while (True):
    try:
        a, b = map(int, raw_input().split())
        print a ^ b
    except:
        break`

This is accepted on the judge. You need to read until the file ends.